# React Context doesn't work using Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am simplifying trying to update the [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context) with React.

I would like that when I click the title `Hello CodeSandbox` the loading bar is displayed with the `context api` data.

Code example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vyq3r7k4o5

## Loading using Context

```
export const LoadingState = {
  loading: false
};
const LoadingContext = React.createContext(LoadingState);

export const LoadingProvider = LoadingContext.Provider;
export const LoadingConsumer = LoadingContext.Consumer;

const LinearIndeterminate = function() {
  const { loading } = useContext(LoadingContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {loading && <LinearProgress color="secondary" />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Consumer

```
class App extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    loading: false
  };

  add = () => {
    const currentState = this.state.loading;
    this.setState({ loading: !currentState });
  };

  render() {
    console.info(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1 onClick={this.add}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Loading />
        <LoadingProvider value={this.state}>
          {this.state.loading}
        </LoadingProvider>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Loading` component should reside inside of App context provider.

working app: https://codesandbox.io/s/z6yjl04vjx

```
 class App extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    loading: false
  };

  add = () => {
    const currentState = this.state.loading;
    this.setState({ loading: !currentState });
  };

  render() {
    console.info(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1 onClick={this.add}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <LoadingProvider value={this.state}>
           <Loading /> /* This line is moved. */
        </LoadingProvider>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is disappointing. As I want to have the loading on a global route `<Route path='/*' />` and then edit the value from any component. I guess I really will have to use `Mobx` then