# Edit React state with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-scope

I would like to have a global variable that I can edit anywhere using hooks.

In the example I have 2 components both using the same hook. It seems to me that the `External toggle` is editing its own scoped `count` and `Internal Toggle` is changing its own scope also.

Is it possible have both toggles edit the same data?

Code example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/520zvyjwlp

## index.js

```
function ChangeCount() {
  const { count, increment } = useCounter();
  return <button onClick={() => increment(!count)}>External Toggle</button>;
}

function App() {
  const { count, increment } = useCounter();
  return (
    <div>
      {`${count}`}
      <br />
      <ChangeCount />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => increment(!count)}>Internal Toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

## useCount.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function useCounter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(false);
  const increment = (changeCount) => setCount(changeCount);
  return { count, increment };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed custom hooks is for sharing *stateful logic*, not actual *state*.

If you want to share a piece of state you can use the [`context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) feature and pass the `count` variable and the `increment` function in an object to the `value` prop of the `Provider` and consume it further down the tree with `useContext`.

**Example**

```js
const { createContext, useContext, useState } = React;
const CounterContext = createContext();

function ChangeCount() {
  const { increment } = useContext(CounterContext);
  return <button onClick={increment}>External increment</button>;
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  function increment() {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }

  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={{ count, increment }}>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <ChangeCount />
      <button onClick={increment}>Internal increment</button>
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @tholle. My biggest problem is that I am unable to wrap the `data` that I need with a provider. The particular thing I am trying to achieve is to have my globally accessible `<Loader />` component display the loading icon whenever data is edited, and then turn it off once the loading as finished. I fear I am going to have to use `mobx` for this now.

Comment: @JamieHutber You could use context with a `Provider` with e.g. `isLoading, setLoading`, and your `<Loader />` component uses `isLoading` through context to show the loading indicator or not, and other components can use `setLoading` to change its value.

Comment: Interesting, I did actually try this I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55299339/react-context-doesnt-work-using-provider there is an example in there too.

Comment: @JamieHutber Ah, I see. [You could do something like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvpqz3l81v).

Comment: Great work around Tholle. It feels like a slight anti pattern though I must say. I assume most of the time the context and hook api's are really designed to be used this way. Which strikes me as odd, I always saw this as a redux replacement no?

Answer (score 1):

To complete this task, you should share your state via the context API,

consider the following:

```
const CounterContext = React.createContext({
  count: 0,
  increment: () => null,
});

const changeCount = () => {
  const counter = useContext(CounterContext);

  return <button onClick={() => counter.increment(!counter.count)}>External Toggle</button>;
}

const App = () => {
  const { count, increment } = useCounter();
  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={{ count, increment }}>
      {`${count}`}
      <br />
      <ChangeCount />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => increment(!count)}>Internal Toggle</button>
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

for more information please visit: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html